# How to add modifers to regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to add these two modifiers: g - global , i - insensitive

here is a par of my script:

```
search_pattern =  r"/somestring/gi"
pattern = re.compile(search_pattern)

queries = pattern.findall(content)
```

but It does not work
the modifiers are as per on this page https://regex101.com/

Comment: You have `findall`, it is `g`. `i` can be added as `re.I` in `pattern = re.compile(search_pattern, re.I)`. `search_pattern =  r"/somestring/gi"` -> `search_pattern =  r"somestring"`. You can actually get the code from the [*code generator* section at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nS4xV3/1).

Comment: Now we get questions about how to use regex101. I believe such question should not be here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I suggest that you should study regex101.com capabilities by checking all of its resources and sections. You can always see Python (and PHP and JS) code when clicking *code generator* link on the left.

**How to obtain `g` global search behavior?**

The `findall` in Python will get you matched texts in case you have no capturing groups. So, for `r"somestring"`, `findall` is sufficient.
In case you have capturing groups, but you need the whole match, you can use `finditer` and access the `.group(0)`.

**How to obtain case-insensitive behavior?**

The `i` modifier can be used as `re.I` or `re.IGNORECASE` modifiers in `pattern = re.compile(search_pattern, re.I)`. Also, you can use inline flags: `pattern = re.compile("(?i)somestring")`.

**A word on regex delimiters**

Instead of `search_pattern =  r"/somestring/gi"` you should use `search_pattern =  r"somestring"`. This is due to the fact that flags are passed as a separate argument, and all actions are implemented as separate `re` methods.

So, you can use

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'somestring', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = "somestring"
re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Or

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?i)(some)string')
test_str = "somestring"
print([(x.group(0),x.group(1)) for x in p.finditer(test_str)])
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/SWqJP3)

Answer (score 1):

When I started using python, I also wondered the same. But unfortunately, python does not provide special delimiters for creating regex. At the end of day, regex are just string. So, you cannot specify modifiers along with string unlike javascript or ruby.

Instead you need to compile the regex with modifiers.

```
regex = re.compile(r'something', re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
queries = regex.findall(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
search_pattern =  r"somestring"
pattern = re.compile(search_pattern,flags=re.I)
                                          ^^^   
print pattern.findall("somestriNg")
```

You can set `flags` this way.`findall` is `global` by default.Also you dont need `delimiters` in python.